# Force Atlas to print only pages with selected features in map

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have a layer with around 3000 points. I created a special print composer and I would like an Atlas that will print only pages with the selected features in the map.

Is there a way to force the Atlas to select only these pages?

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but it doesn't work. It says the expression is_selected() is invalid in 2.18 and in 3.8 it says no matching feature found.
I don't understand how they can even get it working in 2.18 since the expression is not even existing in the Expression filter.

Comment: As answer state, is for 3.*. In 2.* is_selected expression dont exist. And this solution work. I use it at daily work.

Comment: Share screenshot of virtual field formula and atlas  configuration section of print composer into the question.

Comment: I think I recall that 2.18 had a different function that was equivalent to `is_selected()` in QGIS 3.x. Search "select" in the expression builder help and see if you can find it. Also, when you need a solution in a specific version of QGIS you should mention that in your question.

Comment: Using is_selected with print atlas filter was fixed in 3.10

Comment: @ndawson Yes I finally got it working with the 3.9 nightly. So that's probably a longtime bug. So for I'll ask the IT to upgrade the 3.4 LTR to the next LTR. Now I have to find a solution for version 2.18. I'll give a try to this : https://gist.github.com/kgjenkins/fc4664ddd66906957069538e89acc454

Answer (score 0):

So, after some trials :
Using the `is_selected()` function in v3 doesn't work, except by using the 3.9 nightly. So it should be fixed in the upcoming 3.10 LTR version.

For version 2.18, I tried by making a custom expression in python as explain in this post:
https://gist.github.com/kgjenkins/fc4664ddd66906957069538e89acc454

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom')
def isSelected(value1,feature, parent):
    selected_ids = [f.id() for f in iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()]
    return feature.id() in selected_ids
```

I called it `is_selected()` just like in v3 and it did the job as well.